# Are pignus, pinguedo, & piger etymologically related?

Tags: etymology, word-comparison, noun

Are [*pignus*](https://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/morph?la=la&l=pignus#lexicon) (pledge), [*pinguedo*](https://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/morph?la=la&l=pinguedo#lexicon) (fat), and [*piger*](https://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/morph?la=la&l=piger#lexicon) (lazy person) etymologically related?

[de Vaan](https://isidore.co/calibre/#panel=book_details&book_id=5930) p. 465 says:

> The etymology [of [*pignus*](https://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/morph?la=la&l=pignus#lexicon)] is uncertain, since one can imagine a meaning "pledge, surety" to have originated from many different concrete usages.

Why couldn't "fat" be one of them?

Comment: no, they come from three different proto-indo-european (PIE) roots

Comment: @Laravel Perhaps you can turn your comment into an answer. [de Vaan](https://isidore.co/calibre/#panel=book_details&book_id=5930) p. 465 says "The etymology [of _pignus_] is uncertain, since one can imagine a meaning 'pledge, surety' to have originated from many different concrete usages." Why couldn't "fat" be one of them?

Comment: I'm not a downvoter, but I suspect those who did did so because you don't really give an indication *why* you think they might be related. Doing so should alleviate that concern, especially since you already hint at it in your above comment.